# Actually, when does the computer give an audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audit

Sometimes, the first post queue has no post but it suddenly shows up a post. It is very likely to be an audit. Or it is just a real. How is an audit generated to a reviewer? Is it just random or there is some formula or an audit is generated at some time?

There was a [question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13623/when-does-the-website-decide-to-give-you-audits-while-reviewing) asking this few years ago, but I don't understand the comments and there is no answer.

Comment: I feel like this is something only the SE admins would know - it seems like it'd be that sort of "only issued on a need-to-know basis" information the higher-ups keep locked up so people can't try to bot or otherwise game the system.

Comment: As an individual user I find myself getting fewer review audits (which is fine), but I'm not sure whether it's me, the system software or the "luck of the draw" that changes.